# How to remove a user from an Array List?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package main;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserGroup {

  ArrayList<User> userGroup = new ArrayList<>();
  User userOne;
  public UserGroup() {
    addUser(new User("lnb1g16", "Student", "Lee"));
    addUser(new User("hpf1g17", "Staff", "Harry"));
    addUser(new User("jks1g25", "Student", "Jordon"));
  }

  public void addUser(User inUser) {
    //userGroup.add(new User("LeeB123", "Staff", "Lee"));
    userGroup.add(inUser);
  }

  public ArrayList<User> getUserGroup() {
    return userGroup;
  }

  public void removeFirstUser() {
    userGroup.remove(0)
  }
}
```

I've tried creating a method that removes the first user and seems to be compiling but does not actually remove the user when the program is compiled. Any ideas on how to fix this would be great, thanks.

**Main method for calling the program**

```
package main;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int counter=2; counter<=40; counter+=2) {
      System.out.println(counter);
    }
    System.out.println("For loop complete.");

    int counter = 1;
    int increment = 2;
    int loopexeccounter = 0;
    while (counter <= 500) {
      loopexeccounter = loopexeccounter + 1;
      System.out.println(counter);
      counter = counter + increment++;
    }
    System.out.print("This loop iteratted "+loopexeccounter+" times.\n");

    {
      //public User callUserGroup;   
      UserGroup userGroupObject = new UserGroup();

      for (User curUser : userGroupObject.getUserGroup()) {
        System.out.println(curUser.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**User method for declaring user's details**

```
package main;

class User {

  String username;
  String userType;
  String name;

  User(String username, String userType, String name) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
  }

   public String getName() {         
     return name;
  }

   public String setUserType(String admin) {
     return userType = admin;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return username + " " + userType;
   }  
}
```

Comment: How do u know that it is not removing ?

Comment: When I run the program, I can still see the details of the first user

Comment: where is that program ?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue

Comment: How do you run the program? You need to share all code required for reproducing the problem.

Comment: where are you actually calling `removeFirstUser`?

Comment: Ahh silly error, sorry for wasting your time my fault I completely forgot to call the method, that was it

Answer (score 0):

It's working good :

```
`  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserGroup MyUser = new UserGroup();
    for (User curUser : MyUser.getUserGroup()) {
        System.out.println(curUser.toString());
      }
    MyUser.removeFirstUser();
    System.out.println("your user removed!");
    for (User curUser : MyUser.getUserGroup()) {
        System.out.println(curUser.toString());
      }
  }`
```

**RESULT :**

```
`User@4554617c 1
User@74a14482 2
User@1540e19d 3
your user removed!
User@74a14482 1
User@1540e19d 2`
```